# Qual o funcionamento de uma lista encadeada em C?

Tags: c

Estou fazendo um trabalho para a faculdade e ainda não compreendi totalemente a lógica por trás de uma lista encadeada em C.

Eu preciso registrar login, nome e valor em um registro, da qual eu criei uma struct (conjunto de variáveis); eu criei outra struct para serem os meus nodes e uma terceira struct para ser a lita encadeada.

Como essas três structs relacionam-se entre si e por quê todas possuem ponteiros para próximo? Não seria necessário somente os nodos possuírem ponteiros para o próximo?

Há uma diferença dos exemplos tradicionais. Neste exemplo, porque a struct registro possui ponteiro? Não bastaria os ponteiros da struct nodo?

```
typedef struct registro_st{         // sequência de objetos do mesmo tipo
        char login[50];
        char nome[50];
        float valor;
        struct registro *prox;
    } registro;


typedef struct nodo_st{
    registro dado;
    struct nodo *prox;
} nodo;


typedef struct Lista_st{
    nodo *cabeca;
    nodo *cauda;
    int tamanho;
} lista;
```

Answer (score 1):

Eu não sou expert, mas pra mim tem coisas desnecessárias aí, acho que você poderia simplificar para este tipo:

```
typedef struct registro_st{
    char login[50];
    char nome[50];
    float valor;
    struct registro *prox;
} registro;

typedef struct Lista_st{
    registro *cabeca;
    registro *cauda;
    int tamanho;
} lista;
```

Sobre a lista encadeada, basicamente, cada "objeto" da lista, vai apontar para o próximo elemento da lista, se houver. - Isso para simplesmente encadeada. Se for duplamente encadeada, cada "objeto" ao invés de apenas apontar para o próximo, vai apontar também para o anterior.

E no caso do seu código, você vai ter os ponteiros do início e do fim da lista. (cabeça e cauda)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Espero ter ajudado em algo!

Comment: Perfeito! Isso eu compreendo. O que eu não compreendo é o porquê da primeira struct ter um ponteiro auto-referenciado. A lista eu entendo, porque dessa forma podemos apontar a localização do próximo node.

Comment: O ponteiro referenciando ela mesma ja esta auto explicado na foto que o @Tiago postou. A estrutura de todos os dados vão ser os mesmos, e o que irá mudar seria somente o "objeto" no caso o valor. Então ele aponta para o Próximo elemento igual a ele, fazendo assim o encadeamento da lista.